# Click event also fires focus event causing a function to run twice - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know this is probably a simple problem but I can't seem to find anything about it. I have the following code:

```
var moreitemsdiv = $('.moreitemsdiv');

$('.moreitemsanchor').bind("focus click", function(){
    showList(this);
    return false
});

function showList(this_anchor){
    var thismoreitemsdiv = $(this_anchor).next(moreitemsdiv);
    if ($(thismoreitemsdiv).hasClass('focus')) {
        $(thismoreitemsdiv).removeClass('focus');
    } else {
        $(moreitemsdiv).removeClass('focus');
        $(thismoreitemsdiv).addClass('focus');
    }

};
```

The 'focus' class is added on the click but as the click is also a focus, it then removes it as it runs the function again. Do I need to unbind and then re-bind or something?

Any help would be great, cheers!

Comment: try using 'live' instead of 'bind' every thing will remain same including the syntax.

Comment: I don't think `.live` works for `focus` events. Also I don't think that's the problem. `.live` is for when your DOM changes. That's not the case here...

Comment: @user... What are you trying to do? `click` and `focus` are often triggered by the same user action, so that would be problematic (like you're experiencing). Why both events? Try removing `focus` or `click`.

Comment: @Rudie I need it to be keyboard accessible so the focus event needs to be fired if the anchor is tabbed to.

Comment: @Rudie I am not sure how to separate the events while keeping my code DRY you see... I don't know whether I am missing a 'once()' bind (not one()) or a if event == focus?

Comment: You're making your app more accessible by assigning classes with Javascript events? I'm afraid that means you've failed... [Try this one on for size: no Javascript.](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/DNxbC/)

Comment: @Rudie - The links are all available if there is no JS - Why do you think assigning classes with JS Events is inaccessible? It gracefully degrades without JS. The reason JS is used is so that it is easily extended (allows for animation etc), doesn't introduce extraneous mark-up at html level and allows the user to click the anchor to _close_ the actions as well as open them (as well as other various interactions not included here for simplicity). Your solution is good but I am not looking for a pure CSS one.

Comment: @user... I guess I still don't get what you're trying to achieve =) Would you share with us, if you've found the perfect solution? Grazie

Comment: No worries, will do, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML sample too? This question could be reasonable answered, but we need the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var moreitemsdiv = $('.moreitemsdiv');

            //            $('.moreitemsanchor').bind('focus', function (e) {
            //                showList($(this));
            //            });

            //            function showList(this_anchor) {
            //                var thismoreitemsdiv = this_anchor.next(moreitemsdiv);
            //                if (thismoreitemsdiv.hasClass('focus')) {
            //                    thismoreitemsdiv.removeClass('focus');
            //                } else {
            //                    moreitemsdiv.removeClass('focus');
            //                    thismoreitemsdiv.addClass('focus');
            //                }
            //            };

            $('.moreitemsanchor').bind('focus', function (e) {
                var obj = $(this);
                $('.moreitemsanchor').removeClass('focus');
                obj.addClass('focus');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .focus
        {
            border-color: Green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="moreitemsanchor" value="a" />
    <input type="text" class="moreitemsanchor" value="b" />
    <input type="text" class="moreitemsanchor" value="c" />
    <input type="text" class="moreitemsanchor" value="d" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for text box do not use click and focus for same function. Because when click function occurs  focus event will be fired. so use focus alone it will have both click and focus for same function

Comment: your r trying to add focus css class for current textbox which is focus or clicked?

Comment: Not true cross-browser, unfortunately. Mouse-clicking an anchor doesn't fire the `focus` event in Chrome, so you can't just use the "focus" event. And if you use both the `focus` and `click` events in your handler, you get double execution in Firefox. I'm still looking for a solution to this.